# How to convert photoresistor signal to simple Low/High digital on RPi Pico

Tags: analog-to-digital, pi-pico-w

I'm building a light-triggered sound puzzle for my kids, and I have seven pieces.
A little bit like [this toy](https://www.bcd-jeux.fr/premier-puzzle/8425-puzzle-musical-jungle-haba-4010168229973.html?utm_content=403352900):

My plan was to plug 7 photoresistors to ADC pins on my Raspberry Pi Pico, but actually, there are only 3 ADC pins, right?

Someone advised me to just plug them in regular digital pins, and then just make sure the signal is simply thresholded to yield a High/Low kind of switch.

I'm a total newbie and I'm not sure what components I need to couple to the photoresistor to convert the analog signal to high/low digital one.

Comment: If you want an on/off don't use photoresistors

Comment: @Milliways, can you point me to another direction, then, please?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) You have assumed a solution to a problem (you haven't described) and want us to tell you how. What is wrong with a switch?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, the link tells you what I am trying to build: a puzzle that generates sound when the right piece is on the right spot. So maybe I haven't described the component available at home, but it's unfair to say that the problem is not stated, as this is the very first line

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought this was a site where people helped each other in constructive ways, sometimes going past language-barrier to make sure knowledge would reach anyone around the world. Sorry, I guess I chose the wrong website, then.

Comment: Would you be so kind so as to recommend the name of a nice website that corresponds to the afore-mentioned description, please?

Comment: If you want to detect light use a photodiode or phototransistor. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a photoresistor, as it was the component that looked very much like the one on the toy. So I bought plenty of them on AliExpress, and then only I realised that I had only 3 ADC pinouts. I thought I was doomed until someone told me it was not a problem: I just searched for what he tried to explain, and I think he was suggesting something like the "voltage divider" answer here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29074/use-photocell-as-digital-input

Comment: I guess I will try this solution and order some photodiodes in parallel. Then I'll edit this post according to my new findings.

Comment: If you already have photoresistors you could use them. You need to determine the resistance when "on" then make a voltage divider to produce 1.2V which is the nominal GPIO threshold (actual 0.8V - 2.2V) This is very dependent on actual component tolerances whereas photodiodes are ON or OFF.

Comment: IMHO, the best solution for your application is to use an 8-channel **multiplexed** ADC - alternatively, use 2x 4-channel mux'd ADCs. A popular & widely used 8-ch mux ADC is the ***MCP3008***. You can find sample code in the usual places ([Adafruit website](https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython), [GitHub](https://github.com/romilly/pico-code/blob/master/docs/mcp3008.md), etc). Basically, the scheme is to use I2C or SPI serial bus to control which input channel (photoresistor) to read, and make decisions from the *digitized*, mux'd outputs.

Comment: it may be simpler to use switches ... something like two contacts on the base and a piece of metal foil on back of the puzzle piece ... or reed switches and magnets

Answer (score 0):

Make multiple voltage dividers that all use the same lower resistor.

Pull one GPIO pin high.

Set the others to `input`, which effectively disconnects them.

Read the voltage.

Repeat for each LDR (light dependent resistor)

```
      GP1     GP2     GP3
       |       |       |
      LDR1    LDR2    LDR3
       |       |       |
       +--------------------- analog input
       |
       R
       |
       |
      GND
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the LDR is normally illuminated and you require to detect when the light is obscured.

An LDR is not the ideal device for an ON/OFF circuit and is normally used in applications requiring a level depending on illumination but can be used if your application is either fully lighted or dark.

The resistance of a photoresistor (LDR) decreases with increasing incident light intensity.

Ideally you need to determine the LDR resistance when illuminated then make a voltage divider to produce < 1.2V which is the nominal GPIO threshold (actual 0.8V - 2.2V).

Most LDR will have very high resistance if totally in the dark so the actual resistance when illuminated is not critical.

I would try the following which should result in a voltage close to 3.3V when dark.
You may need to vary the resistance to ensure the voltage is < 0.8V when illuminated to ensure reliable operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9fOso.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>